# View font characters for fonts not installed

Tags: windows, fonts, unicode, characters

This question assumes a Windows system.

For installed fonts, one can use Windows' [Character Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_Map) to view the available characters of those fonts (with their Unicode codes). Even better is the "Symbol" view in Microsoft Office Word.

What can I use to view the available characters in fonts that I have not installed on my system? The only program I have found which lets me do anything with uninstalled fonts is [Opicon](http://opcion.sourceforge.net/), but it only displays a "sample text", not the available characters.

Answer (score 2):

[Babelmap](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/software/babelmap.html) does what you (i.e. I) are looking for. It's freeware and portable.